# sending over page number in html form

Tags: html, get

I am trying to send over a page number to a page using a html form. The problem is every-time the form is submitted, it overwrites the page GET value, with all the other GET values being sent over from the form.

the form is below

```
<form action="searchPage.php?page=0" method="get">
<label for="search" id="searchLabel">Search:</label>
<input type="text" size="30" name="search" id ="search" value="<?php echo $_GET['search'] ?>" />
<label for="XML" id="XMLLabel">XML</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="XML" value="Xml" />
<input type="submit" value="Search" name="searchButton" id="searchButton" /> 
<input type="submit" value="Browse" name="browseButton" id="browseButton" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use a hidden input field to pass the page number.

```
<input type="hidden" name="page" value="0"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

`<form action="searchPage.php?page=0" method="get">`

to

```
<form action="searchPage.php" method="get">
   <input type="hidden" name="page" value="0">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a hidden element on the form with the value.

```
  <input type="hidden" name="page" value="<?php echo $_GET['page'] ?>" />
```

This way the user does not see the value but it is sent every time.